# Бэкенд и фронтенд на разных портах localhost, из-за этого возникают проблемы с куками

Tags: node.js, express, vite

Когда пользователь входит в аккаунт, фронтенд (Vite) на порте 5173 отправляет запрос бэкенду (Express) на порте 80. Сервер обрабатывает запрос и отправляет заголовок `Set-Cookie: token=...; Domain=.localhost`. Но из соображений безопасности браузер блокирует установку куков. Как мне настроить/изменить код на сервере и на клиенте так, чтобы во время отладки я мог переносить куки при запросах с одного порта на другой? В режиме production проблем не возникает, так как бэкенд и фронтенд на одном сервере, но в режиме development они располагаются на разных серверах.